# What is this (128 + 127 *) part of these formulas for riffwave.js?

Tags: javascript, waveform, synthesizer

I'm trying to do some javascript music synth in browser, and I came across riffwave.js.  From this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326396/get-precise-notes-with-riffwave-js), the answer gives a hint on how one could use riffwave.js.

I've worked through it a bit to figure out some things like multiple tones, and I understand nearly all of it, but I don't know why there's the `128 + 127 *` in there.

It also shows up [here](http://www.codebase.es/riffwave/) in this demo page.

Can anyone offer an explination or tell me how I can use that part to modify the program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples that you referenced show an equation in the form:

```
A=128 + 127 * Sin(...)
```

Since the `Sin` function can vary from -1 to +1, the result of the above equation is 1-255.  So, adding the constant `128` and multiplying by the coefficient `127`, this is basically a `sin` function whose output varies between 1 and 255, which is convenient because it can be stored using 8 bits (or 1 byte).

Comment: And this particular part of the formula should *not* be adjusted! The code expects values in this range -- unsigned byte only. To change the note, alter the formula after it (making sure the result is -1..1).

Comment: @Jongware thanks for the input.  I discovered the part after had to vary between -1..1 when I started trying to get multiple tones at once, and my solution was to add up the tones and divide by the number being used.

Answer (score 1):

Like mti2935 said, it's a convenient way of mapping a number that can vary from -1 to 1 to an integer varying from 1 to 255, which fits nicely in a byte. In particular, it seems that riffwave internally represents sound in 8-bit .wav format, so this converts floating-point numbers into the 8-bit integer format required to actually play the sound.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Do you know of other methods that do something similar using more than 8-bits?  The sound quality isn't exactly where I'd like it to be, and maybe more than 8-bit sound would make it better?  If not, that's fine; that issue is more on the back-burner for now.

Comment: Looking at riffwave, you'll have to either modify riffwave, use a different library, or write your own. The actual sound-playing mechanism seems to be the HTML5 Audio tag ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio) [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)), which supports other file formats that you could use. I don't know much about the WAV file format, so you may be able to still use WAV with only minor modifications to riffwave, like a change in the file header to allow for 16-bit or higher sound or something. It may also be helpful to make the sampling rate faster.

Comment: It seems that you'd want to try some modifications to the format chunk; the RIFFWAVE format is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#RIFF_WAVE). In particular, I'd try changing that 128+127*sinx to 32768+32767*sinx and doing `wave.header.bitsPerSample = 16;` before you call `wave.Make(data)`.